# Why does the Controller Update Method gets called twice

Tags: laravel

The update is getting called twice. Dumping "hello" outputs 2 results and an error

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target class [config] does not exist.
```

Without dumping there is no binding resolution error, but the update is getting called again.

Controller

```
    public function update(SchedulesRequest $scheduleRequest, ScheduleDayTimesRequest $scheduleDayTimesRequest, Schedule $schedule)
{
  $schedulesData = $scheduleRequest->validated();
  $dayTimesData = $scheduleDayTimesRequest->validated();

  //Updating existing upcoming schedule
  if($schedule->start_date->toDateTimeString() >= now()) {
    $schedule->update($schedulesData);

    foreach($dayTimesData['schedule_day_times'] as $dayTime) {
      $schedule->dayTimes()->updateOrCreate(['id' => $dayTime['id']], ['day_name' => $dayTime['day_name'], 'start_time' => $dayTime['start_time'], 'end_time' => $dayTime['end_time']]);
    }
  }
  //Updating existing current schedule
  else if($schedule->start_date->toDateTimeString() < now() && $schedule->end_date->toDateTimeString() >= now()) {
    $schedule->update(['end_date' => $scheduleRequest['start_date']]);
    $scheduleRecord = Schedule::create($schedulesData);//Change start date
    $scheduleRecord->dayTimes()->createMany($dayTimesData['schedule_day_times']);
  }

  //Removing scheduledaytimes that have null in both start_time and end_time
  $deleteIdList = collect($scheduleDayTimesRequest->all())->get('delete_id_list', null);

  if($deleteIdList != null)
    $schedule->dayTimes()->whereIn('id', $deleteIdList)->delete();

  return redirect($schedule->path());
}
```

The Path in model is :

```
class Schedule extends Model
{
//Some lines of code

    public function path()
    {
      return '/schedules' . $this->id;
    }

}
```

There are some validation rules in the Request file.

ScheduleTest

```
    /** @test */
public function schedule_can_be_updated()
{
  $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
  $this->post('/schedules', $this->data());

  $schedule = Schedule::first();

  $response = $this->patch('/schedules/'. $schedule->id, $this->updateData());

  $schedule->refresh();

  $this->assertEquals(6, $schedule->location_id);
  $this->assertEquals(6, $schedule->service_id);
  $this->assertEquals(6, $schedule->user_id);
  $this->assertEquals(Carbon::tomorrow()->toDateTimeString(), $schedule->start_date->toDateTimeString());
  $this->assertEquals(Carbon::now()->addDays(5)->toDateTimeString(), $schedule->end_date->toDateTimeString());
  $this->assertEquals(5, $schedule->dayTimes()->find(1)->day_name);
  $this->assertEquals(7, $schedule->dayTimes()->find(4)->day_name);
  $this->assertCount(4, $schedule->dayTimes()->get());
  $this->assertEquals(Carbon::parse('08:00 am')->format('H:i'), $schedule->dayTimes()->first()->start_time);
  $this->assertEquals(Carbon::parse('11:00 am')->format('H:i'), $schedule->dayTimes()->first()->end_time);
  $this->assertEquals(2, $schedule->created_by_user_id);
  $response->assertRedirect($schedule->path());
}

 private function updateData()
    {
      return [
        'location_id' => 6,
        'service_id' => 6,
        'user_id' => 6,
        'start_date' => Carbon::tomorrow(),
        'end_date' => Carbon::now()->addDays(5),
        'schedule_day_times' => array(array('id' => 1, 'day_name' => 5, 'start_time' => Carbon::parse("08:00 am")->format("H:i"), 'end_time' => Carbon::parse("11:00 am")->format("H:i")),
                                      array('id' => 2, 'day_name' => 2, 'start_time' => Carbon::parse("01:00 pm")->format("H:i"), 'end_time' => Carbon::parse("02:00 pm")->format("H:i")),
                                      array('id' => 3, 'day_name' => 2, 'start_time' => Carbon::parse("03:00 pm")->format("H:i"), 'end_time' => Carbon::parse("05:00 pm")->format("H:i")),
                                      array('id' => 4, 'day_name' => 7, 'start_time' => Carbon::parse("06:00 pm")->format("H:i"), 'end_time' => Carbon::parse("08:00 pm")->format("H:i")),
                                    ),
        'created_by_user_id' => 2,
      ];
    }
```

The test is failing. But if I replace the update method with the below code the test passes.

```
 public function update(SchedulesRequest $scheduleRequest, ScheduleDayTimesRequest $scheduleDayTimesRequest, Schedule $schedule)
{
  $dayTimesData = $scheduleDayTimesRequest->validated();

  $schedule->update($scheduleRequest->validated());

  foreach($dayTimesData['schedule_day_times'] as $dayTime) {
    $schedule->dayTimes()->updateOrCreate(['id' => $dayTime['id']], ['day_name' => $dayTime['day_name'], 'start_time' => $dayTime['start_time'], 'end_time' => $dayTime['end_time']]);
  }

  $deleteIdList = collect($scheduleDayTimesRequest->all())->get('delete_id_list', null);

  if($deleteIdList != null)
    $schedule->dayTimes()->whereIn('id', $deleteIdList)->delete();

  return redirect($schedule->path());
}
```

The above test passes but update is still getting called twice.

Comment: It's a logical problem so its identify is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `BindingResolutionException` on `config` that means you're trying to load the config dependancy somewhere when the app is not yet fully booted.

Do you have any custom ServiceProviders which try to resolve the config dependancy before the `ConfigServiceProvider` is included?

It would also be helpful if you could post the entire stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: I renamed the test from schedule_can_be_updated to somethingelse and that worked for me. Then I restarted command prompt PHP artisan, renamed my test back to original name schedule_can_be_updated. That started working. Now, this is very strange to me. And the problem was very hard to track. Thankfully, it is solved now. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the test from schedule_can_be_updated to somethingelse and that worked for me. Then I restarted command prompt PHP artisan, renamed my test back to original name schedule_can_be_updated. That started working. Now, this is very strange to me. And the problem was very hard to track. Thankfully, it is solved now